Not receiving client headers in google cloud function
I am using Google cloud functions, and has deployed and had been using 2nd gen functions with flask applications. I am using Hasura actions to trigger these functions. Recently after I updated and deployed my code, it started showing headers that I passed from Hasura actions as None. All cloud functions other than that which I updated was getting the headers. Has anyone got this issue of not receiving the headers that was sent?
To confirm, I updated one more cloud function and that too started acting the same way. I have logged all the headers that I am receiving in the cloud functions and confirmed that it was not any spelling mistakes or that kind of errors.

I am using python version 3.11 and cloud function 2nd gen.

import json

@functions_framework.http
def main(request):
    try:
        action_secret = request.headers.get("action_secret")

        if action_secret != os.environ.get("action_secret"):
            logging.error("Unauthorized access")
            return json.dumps(
                {"err_msg": "You are not authorized to perform this action"}
            )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # I get the error log as action_secret is not in request.headers

Update:

I had been testing this is in multiple ways and found out that it is the issue of Hasura not sending the headers.


Please edit the question to show the code that's not working the way you expect.  We should be a able to duplicate the problem using the code and instructions you provide.

@DougStevenson , actually its not an error in the code but the missing of client headers in cloud function after updating and re-deploying. Either way, I have added a code snippet which shows how I am accessing the headers.

Some header names are reserved and removed link, but action_secret is not one of those. Modify your code to list each HTTP header as a debug step. How did you verify that the header is being sent in the HTTP request to your function instance? Use the curl CLI to test headers when sending requests to your function instance.

@JohnHanley, I had been using these for past two months. As you said, now I tested these functions by exposing them using ngrok and using that exposed url in Hasura actions. Seems like it's the issue of Hasura actions not passing the headers.

Found out that the error was caused due to an underscore in the hasura action client headers. The variable I used was 'action_secret' and when I modified that into 'actionsecret', the cloud functions started working normally.

Based on your last comment: Why did it work for the past two months and now fail?

@JohnHanley https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78361018/google-cloud-function-headers-are-not-received-in-the-endpoint/78361040#78361040
Hey, I got the same issue and found out Google apparently now removes headers with underscores in them.
All my old functions that I haven't updated recently still work, seems like a bug google introduced in some of their cloud function middleware recently
