Google Cloud Function - Headers are not received (in the endpoint)
Custom request headers are not "arriving"/being received by my google cloud function after I deployed an updated version of them this morning.
Notes:

I did not change any code related to request headers/response headers
This error is reproducible across python 3.9-3.12
I haven't changed any GCP networking settings in the past 7 days
Not using a VPN
Headers are not received both when sending a request from browser and when sending a request from a python script

Just to be sure it was Google Cloud Functions causing this I setup a new function to test this:
import functions_framework
from flask import make_response

@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    print(request.headers)


    response = make_response('Hello World')
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    return response

Here is the python script I used to test for this issue/send requests:
import requests 

resp = requests.get("<google_cloud_function_url>/test-headers-1", headers = {
    "custom_header_example" : "custom header value",
})

print(resp)
print(resp.headers)

And finally these are the headers received by the cloud function (custom_header_example is nowhere to be found) 
If anyone knows what is causing this I'd be very grateful for help, I've been using GCP Cloud Functions for over 2 years now without this issue ever, seems like it might be something GCP changed recently

Solution: Google seems to auto remove any headers that have a underscore "_" in them
So "custom_header_example" gets removed by Google somewhere along the line, but "custom-header-example" does not get removed
This is extremely strange behaviour honestly and seems like some bug Google may have introduced in some middleware they have
If anyone knows someone that works at GCP and sees this please let them know <3

SOLUTION FOUND: Headers cannot contain underscore "_"
So I was testing and noticed only headers with underscores were not being received by the google cloud function.

So "custom_header_example" would not appear, but if I sent the header as "custom-header-example" the cloud function now suddenly received the header.
If you know anyone that works at GCP please let them know about this bug

Thank you. Underscores are legal in the HTTP spec, but Nginx also ignores underscores by default but is configurable based on this article: https://www.grouparoo.com/blog/dont-use-underscores-in-http-headers
